# Query that joins two table where match exists and removes result if ID exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

This query gets the the ID, First Name, Date of Birth by joining two tables together where a mutual match exists

Example of mutual match:

Amy likes Mary

Mary likes Amy

```
SELECT u.ID, u.firstname, u.dob, i.[Image]
FROM   [dbo].[User] AS u
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS i ON u.ID = i.Id
WHERE  u.ID IN (
         SELECT userB FROM   [dbo].[LikesRefined]
         WHERE  userA = @ID OR userB = @ID
       UNION
         SELECT userB FROM   [dbo].[LikesRefined]
         WHERE  userA = @ID OR userB = @ID
);
```

I want to filter this result by using except clause on another table but I keep getting this error

*All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.*

```
except
(select paidA
from [dbo].[Matches]
WHERE paidA = @ID
AND (userA = @ID or userB = @ID))
end
```

Comment: You can't use `EXCEPT` unless it's returning the same fields as your initial statement (`u.ID, u.Firstname, u.dob, i.image`).  It would be cleaner to exclude with a `WHERE` clause, but I can't provide an example because there is no obvious relationship between `dbo.Matches.PaidA` and `dbo.Users`/`dbo.LikesRefined` based on your example above.

Comment: Maybe you could use `NOT IN (select paidA...`>

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the union? A union effectively stacks two queries on top of each other and then finds distinct values in the result. Therefore, if you are unioning two queries, they must have the same columns in the same order.

Comment: Did you really mean to say `(select userB ... union select userB)`?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg [Example of two tables](http://i.imgur.com/OvKmajj.png)

Comment: My meager intellect still isn't getting it.  Perhaps you could describe in plain english what your `EXCEPT` statement is attempting to exclude?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Tom logs on to his computer to get dating matches. He logs in and he is shown his users matches the( ID, First Name, Date of Birth) of every user that has matched with him. He has the option to pay for a date. Once Tom pays for a date I want to remove that user from Tom's Dating matches. That's why I was trying to use the `EXCEPT`

Get Toms matches except the matches where he has paid for the date.

Comment: @user3922757 Please use http://sqlfiddle.com/ for questions like these.  You'd probably get much more accurate answers in a shorter space of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused, but I think this may do the trick:

```
SELECT  u.ID ,
        u.firstname ,
        u.dob ,
        i.[Image]
FROM    [dbo].[User] AS u
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Images] AS i ON u.ID = i.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.[LikesRefined] lr ON (u.ID = lr.userA OR u.ID = lr.userB)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Matches m ON u.ID = m.paidA
                                         AND ( m.userA = u.ID OR m.userb = u.ID )
WHERE   (lr.userA = @ID OR lr.userB = @ID)
        AND m.paidA IS NULL
```

We get rid of the union operator and just check for the ID in either userA or userB in the LikeRefined table.  Then we left join to dbo.Matches and just look for records where there is no match.

Comment: I tried your query but it returned [this](http://i.imgur.com/PVsu1zu.png). My original query returns [this](http://i.imgur.com/zcOK2QN.png). Sorry about this being confusing, really appreciate your help. I think I'm just going to add another column to LikesRefined.

Comment: It looks like it's just also returning the person doing the search.  Try just adding u.ID <> @ID in the where clause?

Comment: I added a new column `firstPaid` to my LikesRefined table. Added
`AND lr.firstPaid IS NULL` and now it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

When using union operator all select statements must have the same number of columns

Comment: He has the same fields selected between his UNION operator - the problem is with the EXCEPT operator.